# jquery show/hide on form submit?

Tags: jquery, coffeescript, show-hide

I have coffeescript/jquery that hides DIVs when a page is first loaded:

```
$ ->
  $('#ticket_location,#ticket_issue').hide()
```

But when the form is submitted, I want it to show the fields instead of hiding.

I have this, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
$ ->
  $("form#new_ticket").submit ->
    $('#ticket_location,#ticket_issue').show()
```

What am I doing incorrectly? I have a feeling it is that the first event, to hide(), is overriding the onSubmit event, to show()?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$ ->
  $("form#new_ticket").submit (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    $('#ticket_location,#ticket_issue').show()
```

Comment: Thanks for help. Unfortunately that does not show the hidden DIVs.

Comment: My guess was that form submit results in page reloading... Consider creating a small demo on jsfiddle.net.

Comment: The page does reload.

Comment: Even with `e.preventDefault()`?